# SEO Service - Refresh SEO

Tags: seo

I've been approached to possible take over SEO/marketting work for a site. The guy is currently using a paid service at http://refreshseo.com/ and paying around $80p/m. From what I can make out all refreshseo does is automatically generate keyword rich content pages and attach them to the site. These pages aren't actually linked to from within the site.

So I'm wondering two things

1. has anyone had any experience with this particular company or similar types - has it been worth it?
2. How do you think the recent Google Panda updates impacts on this kind of strategy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I took a brief look at their website and it doesn't look like they offer any service of any real value. It looks like they do glorified link exchanges and article submissions. These are known to be ineffective for SEO. Link exchanges have little value since they are obviously traded links which have almost no value unless the other site is the 900 pound gorilla in the industry (and they never are). Low quality articles are exactly what the Panda algorithm is rooting out.

If someone were to ask me my opinion of this kind of service it would be to stay away. These tactics simply don't work. And depending on how their plug-ins work, you may run the risk of Google determining that you are trying to manipulate your rankings and penalize your site.